# Navigating a multidimensional array with dynamic

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to figure out why it is that I cannot access the follow array with this statement:

```
var_dump($thevar[0]['product_id']);

Array
(
    [d142d425a5487967a914b6579428d64b] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 253
            [variation_id] => 
            [variation] => 
            [quantity] => 1
            [data] => WC_Product Object
                (
                    [id] => 253
                    [product_custom_fields] => Array
                        (
                            [_edit_last] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1
                                )

                            [_edit_lock] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1345655854:1
                                )

                            [_thumbnail_id] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 102
                                )
```

I can, however, access the 'product_id' using the dynamically created array name:

```
print_r($thevar['d142d425a5487967a914b6579428d64b']['product_id']);
```

The issue is, I don't know what that dynamic name is going to be on the fly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because PHP array are associative therefor you have to access them by key.

But you may use [`reset($thevar)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) to get first item.

Or [`array_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
array_values($thevar)[0]
```

Or if you feel like overkill you may also use [`array_keys()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and use the `[0]` element to address element like this:

```
$thevar[ array_keys($thevar)[0]]
```

Comment: So I in fact DO need to find out what that Key is in order to navigate it.

Comment: No, you may also use `array_values` (as I mentioned), but that would create new array. Using `reset()` should be really the fastest way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options for such scenarios.

#### Manually iterate over the array

You can use `reset`, `next`, `key` and/or `each` to iterate over the array (perhaps partially).

For example, to grab the first item regardless of key:

```
$item = reset($thevar);
```

#### Reindex the array

Sometimes it's just convenient to be able to index into the array numerically, and a small performance hit is not a problem. In that case you can reindex using `array_values`:

```
$values = array_values($thevar);
$item = $values[0]; // because $values is numerically indexed
```

#### Iterate with foreach

This would work for a single value as well as it works for more, but it might give the wrong impression to readers of the code.

```
foreach($thevar as $item) {
    // do something with $item
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the array key is dynamic you might find the PHP function array_keys() useful.

It will return an array of the keys used in an array. You can then use this to access a particular element in the array.

See here for more:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php